# Will this routine correctly return signed little-endian ints on big-endian machines?

Tags: c, endianness

**E d i t
--------------**

The comment under [Convert Little Endian to Big Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275955/) provides the practical answer... just   **man endian**   and you'll find the already-existing library functions htole16() and htole32() (I didn't really need 8). No need to re-invent the wheel (especially when my wheel apparently doesn't work so well). Original question below...

The following routine and test driver seem to work okay, as tested on my little-endian intel i7 box, where it's "much ado about nothing" (i.e., a lot of code for a no-op), but I don't have access to any big-endian architecture to test it on. Also, [Little-Endian Signed Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894262/) still leaves me a little confused about exactly how negative values should be handled. Here's the code I'd like validated, along with a test driver, followed by a few further comments...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
/* --- entry point --- */
int littlend ( int word, int size, unsigned char *target ) {
  /* ---
   *  word (I)     (int)-type integer whose `size` least significant
   *               byte values are to be stored in little-endian order,
   *               regardless of host order, and signed appropriately
   *  size (I)     8,16,32 = #significant_bytes * 8
   *  target (O)   target[0...size/8-1] is returned containing the value
   *               of `word` in little-endian order, signed appropriately
   * --- */
  uint32_t uword = (  size==8?  (uint8_t)word  :
                     (size==16? (uint16_t)word : (uint32_t)word) );
  /* --- store little-endian ordering (least significant byte first) --- */
  if ( target != NULL )
    while ( (size -= 8) >=0 ) {
      *target++ = uword%256;   /* low-order byte first */
      uword /= 256; }          /* next byte */
  return ( 1 );
  } /* --- end-of-function littlend() --- */

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int  val = ( argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 123456789 );
  int  littlend();
  int8_t  littleval8  = 0;
  int16_t littleval16 = 0;
  int32_t littleval32 = 0;
  unsigned char *valbytes8  = (unsigned char *)(&littleval8);
  unsigned char *valbytes16 = (unsigned char *)(&littleval16);
  unsigned char *valbytes32 = (unsigned char *)(&littleval32);
  littleval8 = 0;  littlend(val,8,valbytes8);
  printf("littlend(8,%d) = %d = %02X\n", val,littleval8,
           (int)valbytes8[0] );
  littleval16 = 0;  littlend(val,16,valbytes16);
  printf("littlend(16,%d) = %d = %02X %02X\n", val,littleval16,
           (int)valbytes16[0],(int)valbytes16[1] );
  littleval32 = 0;  littlend(val,32,valbytes32);
  printf("littlend(32,%d) = %d = %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", val,littleval32,
           (int)valbytes32[0],(int)valbytes32[1],
           (int)valbytes32[2],(int)valbytes32[3] );
  exit ( 0 );
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
```

What I'm trying to do is first: handle the sign-bit and twos-complement stuff by casting the signed input int as an appropriately-sized unsigned int. Then second: handle the byte-ordering in an architecture-independent way by using arithmetic operations % and /, which must be correctly implemented regardless of endianness, e.g., uword%256 is always the value of the low-order byte.

So I'm pretty sure it'll work okay if the input isn't signed (is >=0), but significantly less sure if it's signed. Does it always work??? And, if not, how can it be fixed?

Comment: `(uint8_t)word` those casts make no sense, it's going to be `uint32_t` anyway.

Comment: You only write the lowest 1/2/4 bytes to the destination. There is no need to chop the input value as the extra bits are just not copied.

Comment: @KamilCuk the point -- which may indeed be senseless/wrong/whatever -- is to get the sign bit, if there is any, automatically propagated into the correct byte, which depends on size, I think.

Comment: @Gerhardh if by "chop" you mean /256, that's to automatically get the bytes in address-order if the machine is little-endian, or reverse-address-order if big-endian.

Comment: @JohnForkosh: big endian simply stores bytes in the reverse order. So, if a 16-bit representation of -2000 is 0xF830 with 2s complement, a big-endian architecture will store it store as `F8 30` in memory, while little-endian will store `30 F8`. It doesn't move the sign bit anywhere. Just cast the value to an unsigned int and swap bytes before transmitting the data. Unless you are inspecting individual bytes or transmitting data, you never need to case about endianness, bitwise operations will work exactly the same.

Comment: No, I mean the casts to the shorter types. It will not affect the sign of the used bytes.

Comment: @Hulk I'd presumed bit-shifting wouldn't work because it doesn't account for endianness; it's always based on address-order.

Comment: Bit shifting is acting on numerical values. Storage order in memory is not taken into account at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh Okay, then my right-or-wrong reasoning was like I said to KamilCuk -- to propagate the sign bit from its 4-byte position to the byte appropriate for the caller's desired size.

Comment: Unsigned types do not propagate any signed bit when they are extended to larger type. As you do not store the higher order bytes anyway, whatever might have been sign extected would be lost again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert big endian to little endian in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) Keep in mind that you have absolutely no reason to deal with numbers stored in BE format on a LE machine, the only time you need this is before serializing the data using a protocol which specifies endianness (i.e. before transmitting this data over a network protocol or storing to disk).

Comment: @Gerhardh Right -- I misspoke. The input's always 32 bits, but if you're asking for 16-bit output then the input value is presumably <65536, or half that if signed. But if signed, the "first" two bytes will be the value's twos complement >>without<< the properly-positioned sign bit. By casting it unsigned, the sign bit just becomes part of the value. Then, the caller can re-interpret the output target bytes as a signed int of that size, with the sign bit properly re-placed. --- At least that was the idea.

Comment: @Groo Thanks, I'll take a careful look at those other questions, which my earlier search missed.

Comment: @Hulk Thanks, as per above comment to Groo, I'll take a careful look at those other questions.

Comment: Do you assume the cast might change any bit of the lower 1 or 2 bytes? That will not happen. It will just chop the upper bytes.

Comment: @Gerhardh Okay, thanks. Then I misunderstood.